# How do I properly test a function that use axios.get and cheerios.load functions with mocha and chai?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have this index.js file

```
    const axios = require("axios");
    const cheerio = require('cheerio');

    const fetchData = async (webpage) => {
        const result = await axios.get(webpage);
        return cheerio.load(result.data);
    }
    const extractData = async (webPage) => {
        const $ = await fetchData(webPage);
        const numMains = $('.rank').text();
        //Should return the following string 
        //1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10.11.12.13.14.15.16.17.18.19.20.21.22.23.24.25.26.27.28.29.30.
        return numMains;
    }

    const siteUrl = "https://news.ycombinator.com/";

    (async (webPage) => {console.log(await extractData(webPage));})(siteUrl);

    module.exports = {
        extractData: extractData
    }
```

And I have this test.js file

```
    var chai = require('chai');
    var expect = chai.expect;
    var functionNames = require('../index.js');

    describe('extractData() Unit-Test', () => {
      it('This function should return a given string', () => {

        // 1. ARRANGE
        const siteUrl = "https://news.ycombinator.com/";
        const shouldResult = "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10.11.12.13.14.15.16.17.18.19.20.21.22.23.24.25.26.27.28.29.30.";

        // 2. ACT
        const result = functionNames.extractData(siteUrl);

        // 3. ASSERT
        expect(result).to.be.equal(shouldResult);

      });
    });
```

*I'm not getting pass with this AssertionError: *

```
    AssertionError: expected {} to equal '1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10.11.12.13.14.15.16.17.18.19.20.21.22.23.24.25.26.27.28.29.30.'
```

**Does someone know what I'm doing wrong and how can I solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `await`, you're comparing a `Promise` against `1,2,3`...

```
it('This function should return a given string', async() => {

        // 1. ARRANGE
        const siteUrl = "https://news.ycombinator.com/";
        const shouldResult = "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10.11.12.13.14.15.16.17.18.19.20.21.22.23.24.25.26.27.28.29.30.";

        // 2. ACT
        const result = await functionNames.extractData(siteUrl);

        // 3. ASSERT
        expect(result).to.be.equal(shouldResult);

});
```

Have in mind that you're actually performing the request while doing the test, if the site is down the test will fail. If you don't want that you can mock the request, using `nock` or a similar package.

Comment: Thanks, very useful! :) how can I mock it? can you suggest me an example?

Comment: You're welcome! There are plenty of examples in `nock` documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Marcos's solution, you could also use `eventually` from chai:

```
result.should.eventually.equal(shouldResult);
```

Documentation here: https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/

Comment: Much elegant than the longer expect syntax.